# Docker daemon fails to restart gracefully

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04

Been seeing an intermittent issue with one of my docker deployments.  Basically, the docker daemon fails to restart gracefully.

From syslog:

```
init: docker main process ended, respawning
init: docker main process (14333) terminated with status 1
init: docker respawning too fast, stopped
```

From docker upstart log:

```
FATA[0000]  Error starting daemon: error initializing network controller: could not delete the default bridge network: network bridge has active endpoints
/var/run/docker.sock is up
```

I can fix this issue by running:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/docker/network
sudo service docker start
```

This is running on Ubuntu 14.04.3 on 3.16.0-48-generic using Docker 1.10.0.

Any ideas on a permanent fix for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue was solved in 1.9.1-rc1 of docker but is back 1.10 versions.
You can track the issue at https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17083